# Sublimetext 3 Emacs indentation

Tags: emacs, indentation, sublime-text-3

I'd like to have an indentation like EMACS on Sublimetext when editing ONLY C source code. More specifically I'd like sublime text add 2 spaces of indentation after "{" like in the following example

```
        if (/* condition */)
        {
          a = 13; /*hitting enter after "{" should automatically add 2 spaces of indentation         
        }
```